# How can I fix the error "expression must have pointer-to-object type" (multifile project)?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm writing the program with 2 .cpp files and 1 .h file (direct.h). The main function is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <direct.h>

using namespace std;

int direct(const int rows, const int cols, int ARR); 

int main()
{
const int rows = 9;
const int cols = 9;

int ARR[rows][cols];

direct(const int rows, const int cols, int ARR);

}
```

My function (that fills the array in the spiral way) is:

```
int direct(const int rows, const int cols, int ARR)
{
int val;

// Initialize the array to 0 values
for (int i = 0; i < rows;i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cols;j++) 
    {
        val = 0;
    }
}

// Use symbols for directions
enum dir
{
    left = 0,
    down,
    up,
    right,
}
dir = left;

// Define the starting point and starting value
int x = rows / 2;
int y = cols / 2;
int val = 1;

// A flag to know when to stop
bool stop = false;

// Start
for (;;)
{
    ARR[x][y] = val++;
    switch (dir)
    {
    case left:
        y -= 1;
        if (y < 0) stop = true;
        else if (ARR[x + 1][y] == 0) dir = down;
        break;
    case down:
        x += 1;
        if (x > rows) stop = true;
        else if (ARR[x][y + 1] == 0) dir = right;
        break;
    case right:
        y += 1;
        if (y >= rows) stop = true;
        else if (ARR[x - 1][y] == 0) dir = up;
        break;
    case up:
        x -= 1;
        if (x < 0) stop = true;
        else if (ARR[x][y - 1] == 0) dir = left;
    }
    if (stop) break;
}
}
```

In the main.cpp file everything is OK. However, in direct.cpp file I get the errors that say "expression must have pointer-to-object type" and the variables "x" and "y" are underlined in the loop "for", so the problem is in them.

What am I doing wrong? And how can I fix it?

Comment: What about multiple 'int val' declaration?

Answer (score 0):

Start to Replace

```
int direct(const int rows, const int cols, int ARR)
```

by

```
int direct(const int rows, const int cols, int ARR[][])
```

in the main

call the function :

```
direct( rows, cols, ARR);
```

When you init the tab :

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows;i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cols;j++) 
    {
        ARR[i][j]= 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are issues around the `enum` definition too.

Comment: Also note that the function parameter declaration `int ARR[][]` isn't valid `c++`.

Comment: Questions like this are difficult to answer. I mentioned the `enum` in a question comment, but retracted it as it's one of many issues.